# How to fix "Error CS0165: Use of an unassigned local variable"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling, local-variables

I've been trying to figure out a way to switch animations depending on the value of the horizontalInput through the use of integers. I have encountered a problem though which consists in the error "CS0165".

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float horizontalInput;
    public float runSpeed = 3.0f;

    float verticalInput;

    private Animator anim;
    
    
    
    private enum MovementState { Soldier, Running }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        //Movement
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * runSpeed * horizontalInput);
        
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Time.deltaTime * runSpeed * verticalInput);

       //Switching Animations
       MovementState state;

        if (horizontalInput > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Running;
        }
        else if (horizontalInput < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Running;
        }
        
        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
```

I've been trying to understand what is wrong with my code but can't seem to be able to figure out what I'm missing. Tried adding "state" as a variable, but that did nothing but create other errors, so I'm really not sure what to do and if any of you could point out what's wrong I'd be very thankful.

(P.S. I'm fairly new to coding, and still have quite a bit to learn).

Thank you!

Comment: What would `state` be if `horizontalInput` was 0?

Comment: State should be Soldier (Which should be the idle animation), and if it is anything other than 0 it should just be Running.

Comment: You did not assign it `Soldier`, you assigned it nothing to start with `MovementState state;`. You assigned it nothing, then only assign `Running` if `horizontalInput` is not 0. If it is 0 then `state` has no value assigned - hence the error about potentially using an unassigned variable.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what was wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you’re defining a variable `state` with no default. Then you have an `if`, which will define it and then an `else if` which will define it. But what if neither logic branch matches? Then `state` is still not defined! (Note that this only applies to variables in a method scope. If you define a class-scoped variable, it *will* have a default value although it’s going to be null for any reference type.)

The fix for this is simple. Either define an initial value for `state`, or add a final `else` logic branch to set it to something if the other branches don’t match.

ETA also worth noting you can simplify your logic to just be a single `!= 0f` statement rather than two separate if checks.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: forget about that, it's wrong

I think the error is with `anim` not being initialized.

You do it in `Start` method but the compiler doesn't know about the lifecycle of your program.

You can do `private Animator anim = null;` and check if `anim` is not null before using it in `Update` (or on top of the method)

Comment: Meh, that's not a problem. Mr. @takendarkk hs pointed it out in the comments above.

Comment: @Xander yes you're right, anim is not the problem but state is, as theficus stated above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).